# PHP Explode function. If function

Tags: php, if-statement, explode

Could someone help suggest in below php explode function, we are displaying script after 5th listing. How is it possible to display script exactly after 5th listing and 10th listing on a page which has more than 10 listings

We tried using

```
if ($i == 5 & $i== 10)
```

but it does not work

Below is original code - which displays script after 5th listing

```
   <?php
  $listings = explode("<hr/>", $list);
  $numberOfListings = count($listings);
  for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfListings; ++$i) 
    {
    if ($i == 5) 
    { ?> 

   <script>  </script>

    <?php }
    echo $listings[$i] . "<hr/>";
    }
    ?>
```

**Edit**
How is it like - if have to display a separate script on $i==9, could you advise.

Comment: `if ($i == 4 || $i== 9)` <== use this or start your itetration with `$i=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$i` starts at `0` (`0` to `9` is 10, whilst `0` to `10` is 11). Try `if ($i == 4 || $i== 9)`, with an `or` operator.

Also I would not use the `&&` (the `and` operator), because it is unlikely `$i` will ever equal both `4` and `9`. I'd suggest you read into [Truth Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) (and maybe [Propositional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus)) because from seeing what you had tried originally, it would be helpful to understand how a truth table works.

[image: Truth Table]
<sub>(source: [wlc.edu](http://faculty.wlc.edu/buelow/mfl/truthtable.gif))</sub>

Comment: thnx it works and thnx for reference url too. i will go through it

Comment: Hello, Just a small help.. How is it like - if have to display a separate script on $i=9, could you advise. Am sorryo to not have asked that in first instance. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contine`, continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

```
                $arr = range(0,9);
                foreach($arr as $number) {
                    if($number < 5) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    print $number;
                }
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using modulus operator

```
$listings = explode("<hr/>", $list);
$numberOfListings = count($listings);


for($i = 1; $i < $numberOfListings; ++$i)
    {
    if ($i%5 == 0)
    {
        echo "in";
        ?>
        <script>  </script>
    <?php
    }
    echo $listings[$i-1] . "<hr/>";
}
```

Here we are looping from 1 and there for $i <= $numberOfListings
and while listing we will use $listings[$i-1]

DEMO CODE AT http://codepad.viper-7.com/lrTOgP